# How to empty unselected ajax .tabs() on new tab select

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with ajax .tabs() and emptying or removing the contents of the tabs that aren't selected.  I've searched the jQuery site and found this event, but quite confused as to what's next:

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {

   // All other tabs need to be empty when the new tab is selected
   // Before the selected tab is loaded (ajax)

});
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the [jQuery `.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method using an appropriate [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to apply it to all of your tabs:

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
   // All other tabs need to be empty when the new tab is selected
   // Before the selected tab is loaded (ajax)

   $("a selector for your tabs").empty();

   // ajax to populate the selected tab here
});
```

Where I've said "a selector for your tabs" you just need to put your own [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as appropriate - possibly ".selector", going from the snippet of code you showed, but without seeing your HTML I don't know.

(Note: it should be fine to clear all the tabs included the just selected one given that after you do so you will be repopulating the just selected one anyway...)